# What commands are called during WebSphere Commerce's checkout process / flow?

Tags: e-commerce, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-commerce, wcs

What are *all* the controller commands and task commands that get invoked starting from the AddToCart -> ShoppingCart -> CheckoutSignIn -> ShippingInfo -> ShippingMethod -> PaymentMethod -> Order Summary (basically navigating from the Shopping Cart page to the Order Summary page)? This may be a big question...Are there any links that may provide such an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brief answer here is as follows

(1) to be able to add an item to an cart - OderItemAdd 
(2) to be able to update an item in a cart - OrderItemUpdate 
(3) to delete an item in a cart - OrderItemDelete 
(4) to associate a shipping address to an order - OrderItemUpdate 
(5) to associate a billing address to an order - OrderItemUpdate 
(6) to lock an order in commerce - OrderPrepare 
(7) to submit an order for processing - OrderProcess

Answer (score 6):

I think that link will answer to you question. (scroll down under diagram)

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.developer.doc%2Frefs%2Frosordstattran.htm

You can also take a loot on that page : 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.developer.doc%2Frefs%2Frosordtaskcmdscont.htm

Hope you'll find your answer.

Regards,
Jimmy.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. The links provide a good start, but I was wondering if there was something more in depth. For example, the first link provided mentions OrderItemAddCmd and OrderCreateCmd, which I can look up both of them. However, the results on IBM's WCS7 manual does not mention commands like OrderItemDisplayCmd. I know at some point OrderCalculateCmd and OrderItemDisplayCmd are called. I know these exist, and I can look up those too, but I am trying to figure out everything tied together, in case I may be missing some controller or task command during the checkout process.

Comment: Hi, At that step, the best thing is to find there relations directly by reading the code. You can find the files by using the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + T (or Navigation > Open Type). Regarding to the shopping flow you have, some commands will be used and some not. For OrderItemDisplayCmd, take a look on that link : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.api.doc%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fcommerce%2Forderitems%2Fcommands%2FOrderItemDisplayCmd.html

Comment: By the way, if you realy want a list of all commands you can found on the ordering process, why don't you look all commands in the package com.ibm.commerce.order.* (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.api.doc%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fcommerce%2Forder%2Fcommands%2Fpackage-summary.html)  and  com.ibm.commerce.orderitems.* (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.api.doc%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fcommerce%2Forderitems%2Fcommands%2Fpackage-summary.html). You can also be interested by com.ibm.commerce.payment.*

Answer (score 0):

Here are the controller commands for each subsystem -

**Catalog**

AttributeCreateControllerCmd

ProductPricingControllerCmd

CategoryDisplayControllerCmd

ProductDisplayControllerCmd

GetContractUnitPriceCmd

**Promotion**

PromotionCodeAddRemoveControllerCmd

AddOrderItemWithPromotionCodeOrCouponCmd

CouponAddRemoveControllerCmd

**Member**

PostOrgEntityAddCmd

PostOrgEntityUpdateCmd

CheckUserInMemberGroupCmd

LogonCmdImpl

DBAuthenticationCmd

LDAPAuthenticationCmd

LogoffCmd

**Order**

OrderCreateCmd

OrderItemAddCmd

OrderItemDeleteCmd

OrderItemUpdateCmd

OrderProcessCmd

ProcessOrderCmd

PrepareOrderCmd

PreProcessOrderCmd

OrderCancelCmd

OrderDisplayCmd